# How to compare two columns in separate spreadsheets and if the columns match, output related data in from one spreadsheet to the other

Tags: excel, vlookup

Had a search and sadly couldn't find a related question

Im trying to compare two columns in separate spreadsheets and if the columns match, output related data in from one spreadsheet to the other. In the Screenshot below, I am trying to compare the two "required functionality description" fields which are in separate spreadsheets. Then If the two fields match, output the Importance field from one to the other.

[image: Excel]

I really appreciate any help/guidance on this! Thanks!

Comment: If they match exactly, this is a simple application of `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX-MATCH`.  Do they match exactly?

Comment: @Byron Yeah they should match exactly. Or at least I only want data from  the ones that do.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G6,[SO31165136a.xlsx]Sheet1!$G:$H,2,0),"")
```

adjusted for your sheet and workbook names.